# TikZ: How do I change the path color without changing nodes alongside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

It is difficult to google for this problem, as I use the `to` command in tikz in order to bend edges left or right.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\nodedist}
\setlength{\nodedist}{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      mynode/.style={text width=4cm,draw,rounded
      corners=5pt,shape=rectangle,minimum width=1cm,text depth=2cm,inner sep=5pt},
      node distance=\nodedist,
      arrow label/.style={midway,fill=white,draw,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=3pt},
   ]
   \draw (0,0) node[mynode] (model) {
      \makebox[4cm]{Model}\\
      \hrulefill \\
   };
   \node[mynode,right=of model] (view) {
      \makebox[4cm]{View}\\
      \hrulefill \\
   };

   \node[mynode] (controller) at ($(model) !0.5! (view) + (0,-\nodedist)$) {
      \makebox[4cm]{Controller}\\
      \hrulefill \\
   };
   \draw[->] (controller.west) to[bend left,red]  node[arrow label] {Change state} (model.south);
   \draw[->] (controller.east) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Update display} (view.south);
   \draw[->]  (view.west) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Send user input} (controller.north);
   \draw[->]  (view.north) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Request state} (model.north);
   \draw[->]  (model.east) to[bend left] node[arrow label] {Notify of change} (view.north west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the arrow colour without affecting the nodes placed along it. Is this straightforwardly possible?
I could use `edge` from the graph library, but I wonder if it can be done with `to`.

Comment: Do you want `\draw[->, draw=red]`? This colours everything but the text in the node. If you want just the arrow in red, you will have to modify to `arrow label/.style={midway,fill=white,draw=black,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=3pt}` if feasible.

Comment: I see. Additionally, I have to set `text=black` on `arrow label/.style`  so the text does not get coloured.

Comment: If you have set `\draw[->, draw=red]` and not `\draw[->, red]`, `text=black` should not be needed. Just `draw=black` in your `arrow label` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `scope` with the option

```
every to/.style={append after command={[draw=red]}}
```

Example:

```
\begin{scope}[every to/.style={append after command={[draw=red]}}]
   \draw[->] (controller.west) to[bend left]  node[arrow label] {Change state} (model.south);
   \draw[->] (controller.east) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Update display} (view.south);
   \draw[->]  (view.west) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Send user input} (controller.north);
   \draw[->]  (view.north) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Request state} (model.north);
   \draw[->]  (model.east) to[bend left] node[arrow label] {Notify of change} (view.north west);
   \end{scope}
```

To prevent this from making the node borders red, use `draw=black` in

```
arrow label/.style={midway,fill=white,draw=black,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=3pt},
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\nodedist}
\setlength{\nodedist}{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      mynode/.style={text width=4cm,draw,rounded
      corners=5pt,shape=rectangle,minimum width=1cm,text depth=2cm,inner sep=5pt},
      node distance=\nodedist,
      arrow label/.style={midway,fill=white,draw=black,shape=rectangle,rounded corners=3pt},
   ]
   \draw (0,0) node[mynode] (model) {
      \makebox[4cm]{Model}\\
      \hrulefill \\
   };
   \node[mynode,right=of model] (view) {
      \makebox[4cm]{View}\\
      \hrulefill \\
   };

   \node[mynode] (controller) at ($(model) !0.5! (view) + (0,-\nodedist)$) {
      \makebox[4cm]{Controller}\\
      \hrulefill \\
   };
   \begin{scope}[every to/.style={append after command={[draw=red]}}]
   \draw[->] (controller.west) to[bend left]  node[arrow label] {Change state} (model.south);
   \draw[->] (controller.east) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Update display} (view.south);
   \draw[->]  (view.west) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Send user input} (controller.north);
   \draw[->]  (view.north) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Request state} (model.north);
   \draw[->]  (model.east) to[bend left] node[arrow label] {Notify of change} (view.north west);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same approach as suggested Harish Kumar:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               prewiev]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
    \begin{document}
\newlength{\nodedist}
\setlength{\nodedist}{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = \nodedist,
              draw = red,
     mynode/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners=5pt,
                     text width=4cm, text depth=2cm, inner sep=5pt},
arrow label/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners=3pt, fill=white},
   ]
\draw (0,0) node[mynode] (model) {\hfil Model\\ \hrulefill};
\node[mynode,right=of model] (view) {\hfil View\\ \hrulefill};
\node[mynode] (controller)
    at ($(model)!0.5!(view) + (0,-\nodedist)$) {\hfil Controller\\ \hrulefill};
\draw[->] (controller.west) to[bend left,text=red] node[arrow label] {Change state} (model.south);
\draw[->] (controller.east) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Update display} (view.south);
\draw[->]  (view.west) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Send user input} (controller.north);
\draw[->]  (view.north) to[bend right]  node[arrow label] {Request state} (model.north);
\draw[->]  (model.east) to[bend left] node[arrow label] {Notify of change} (view.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In above code I didn't use scope for making arrows red, just simple declare to be all line red and then nodes define to be draw black. I alo slightly simplify the way of determinning of the main nodes. Obtained results is the same as at answer of Harish Kumar.